# requestAnimationFrame being laggy when redrawing

Tags: canvas, request, lag, requestanimationframe

I am creating a paint like tool using canvas.

I used not to use requestAnimationFrame but the image from the backend containing the paint is being updated as the user is painting (on given condition but it is not the topic here).

As I need my canvas layer holding the paint to be updated as the image is, I am using a dummy query parameters on my image url, like : 'my-path?dummy=current-timestamp'. Then, I faced an issue, when the url was updated, if I am currently redrawing, the image loading is not complete and so the image disappears until the next redraw.

So,I found that using requestAnimationFrame could be a solution for me, so yes, I rewrote some code and indeed my image does not disappear anymore but, now my situation is way worst, I have a LOT of lag with this version, I use to have NO lag at all.

this is my drawing method:

```
const drawImageToCanvas = (currentPoint = []) => {
    if (context && context.canvas.id !== 'preview') {
        context.save();
        context.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        context.restore();

        if (image) {
            context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
        }

        context.beginPath();

        for (let current of currentPoint) {
            const middle = current.w / 2;
            if (current.mode === 'fill') {
                context.fillStyle = current.color;
                context.fillRect(current.x - middle, current.y - middle, current.w, current.w);
            } else {
                context.clearRect(current.x - middle, current.y - middle, current.w, current.w);
            }
        }
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(() => drawImageToCanvas(currentPoint));
};
```

This does not lag as long as I do not draw, meaning I can zoom or drag as much as I want.

Now, this is my drawing method

```
const drawHandler = (e, erase = false) => {
    const middle = brushSize / 2;
    const pos = getMousePos(e);
    const matrix = context.getTransform();
    const imatrix = matrix.invertSelf();

    const x = pos.x * imatrix.a + pos.y * imatrix.c + imatrix.e;
    const y = pos.x * imatrix.b + pos.y * imatrix.d + imatrix.f;

    context.beginPath();

    let mode;
    let currentLabelId;
    let currentColor;
    if (erase) {
        context.clearRect(x - middle, y - middle, brushSize, brushSize);
        mode = 'delete';
        currentLabelId = -1;
        currentColor = 'rgba(0,0,0,1)';
    } else {
        context.fillStyle = color;
        context.fillRect(x - middle, y - middle, brushSize, brushSize);
        mode = 'fill';
        currentLabelId = labelId;
        currentColor = color;
    }

    const point = {
        x: x,
        y: y,
        w: brushSize,
        mode: mode,
        color: currentColor,
        pathindex: pathIndex,
        labelid: currentLabelId
    };


    requestAnimationFrame(() => drawImageToCanvas([ ...drawData, point ]));
};
```

This method is called any time the event onMouseDown is triggered.
As you can see I Call ***requestAnimationFrame(() => draw([ ...drawData, point ]));*** again at the end of the method.
This is causing the lag after 2/3 second of drawing everything is laggy.

Is it a good pratice to call requestAnimationFrame on each draw ?
Should I use requestAnimationFrame for my use case ?

Thanks

Comment: It might simply be a problem that you should debounce your call. Also, you call draw in the mouseDown, and draw call itself... does it mean it does run multiple times per frame?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean about calling draw twice sorry.  I tried to reduce the frame rate and wait for it on the drawImageToCanvas but it does not change anything

Comment: It's quite unclear what you are drawing and why you are using rAF here. If it's just to wait for the image from the server has loaded, then no, rAF os not what you want. Instead listen for the `onload` event of the image. But then, it's jnclear what this image is used for. If it's a collaborative drawing app, send drawing commands to and from your server, not bitmaps.

Comment: It's a 'paint like' application, for ai annotation and the image is storing the drawing, although it does not really matter what the image is for. If I wait for the onload event then my all tool is blocked, you can't paint, you can't zoom or drag or do anything on it, obviously it is very bad user experience

Comment: What is in the `draw` method?

Comment: I rewrote my question, it's drawImageToCanvas :)

Comment: Why would you be unable to do any of these of you wait for image to load? Please show your code taht does handle the image.